# How should I be formatting my yield requests?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scrapy

My scrapy spider is very confused, or I am, but one of us is not working as intended. My spider pulls start url's from a file and is supposed to: Start on an Amazon search page, crawl the page and grab the url's of each search result, follow the link to the items page, crawl the items page for information on the item, once all items have been crawled on the first page follow pagination up to page X, rinse and repeat.

I am using ScraperAPI and Scrapy-user-agent to randomize my middlewares. I have formatted my start_requests with a priority based on their index in the file, so they should be crawled in order. I have checked and ensured that I AM receiving a successful 200 html response with the actual html from the Amazon page. Here is the code for the spider:

```
class AmazonSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon_spider'
    page_number = 2
    current_keyword = 0
    keyword_list = []

    payload = {'api_key': 'mykey', 'url':'https://httpbin.org/ip'}
    r = requests.get('http://api.scraperapi.com', params=payload)
    print(r.text)
#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
def start_requests(self):
    with open("keywords.txt") as f:
        for index, line in enumerate(f):
            try:
                keyword = line.strip()
                AmazonSpiderSpider.keyword_list.append(keyword)
                formatted_keyword = keyword.replace(' ', '+')
                url = "http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=mykey&url=https://www.amazon.com/s?k=" + formatted_keyword + "&ref=nb_sb_noss_2"
                yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'priority': index})
            except:
                continue
#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
def parse(self, response):
    print("========== starting parse ===========")

    for next_page in response.css("h2.a-size-mini a").xpath("@href").extract():
        if next_page is not None:
            if "https://www.amazon.com" not in next_page:
                next_page = "https://www.amazon.com" + next_page
            yield scrapy.Request('http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=mykey&url=' + next_page, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    second_page = response.css('li.a-last a').xpath("@href").extract_first()
    if second_page is not None and AmazonSpiderSpider.page_number < 3:
        AmazonSpiderSpider.page_number += 1
        yield scrapy.Request('http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=mykey&url=' + second_page, callback=self.parse_pagination)
    else:
        AmazonSpiderSpider.current_keyword = AmazonSpiderSpider.current_keyword + 1
#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
def parse_pagination(self, response):
    print("========== starting pagination ===========")

    for next_page in response.css("h2.a-size-mini a").xpath("@href").extract():
        if next_page is not None:
            if "https://www.amazon.com" not in next_page:
                next_page = "https://www.amazon.com" + next_page
            yield scrapy.Request(
                'http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=mykey&url=' + next_page,
                callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    second_page = response.css('li.a-last a').xpath("@href").extract_first()
    if second_page is not None and AmazonSpiderSpider.page_number < 3:
        AmazonSpiderSpider.page_number += 1
        yield scrapy.Request(
            'http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=mykey&url=' + second_page,
            callback=self.parse_pagination)
    else:
        AmazonSpiderSpider.current_keyword = AmazonSpiderSpider.current_keyword + 1
#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    items = ScrapeAmazonItem()

    print("============= parsing page ==============")

    temp = response.css('#productTitle::text').extract()
    product_name = ''.join(temp)
    product_name = product_name.replace('\n', '')
    product_name = product_name.strip()

    temp = response.css('#priceblock_ourprice::text').extract()
    product_price = ''.join(temp)
    product_price = product_price.replace('\n', '')
    product_price = product_price.strip()

    temp = response.css('#SalesRank::text').extract()
    product_score = ''.join(temp)
    product_score = product_score.strip()
    product_score = re.sub(r'\D', '', product_score)

    product_ASIN = response.css('li:nth-child(2) .a-text-bold+ span').css('::text').extract()

    keyword = AmazonSpiderSpider.keyword_list[AmazonSpiderSpider.current_keyword]

    items['product_keyword'] = keyword
    items['product_ASIN'] = product_ASIN
    items['product_name'] = product_name
    items['product_price'] = product_price
    items['product_score'] = product_score

    yield items
```

For the FIRST start url, it will crawl three or four items and then it will jump to the SECOND start url. It will skip processing the remaining items and pagination pages, going directly to the second start url. For the second url, it will crawl three or four items, then it again will skip to the THIRD start url. It continues in this way, grabbing three or four items, then skipping to the next URL until it reaches the final start url. It will completely gather all information on this URL. Sometimes the spider COMPLETELY SKIPS the first or second starting url. This happens infrequently, but I have no idea as to what could cause this.

My code for following result item URL's works fine, but I never get the print statement for "starting pagination" so it is not correctly following pages. Also, there is something [odd with middlewares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FIWj.png). It begins parsing before it has assigned a middleware

Comment: Try reducing the request per minute. How many items are you trying to scrape?

Comment: To go from a method to another you need the parameter `callback=self.spiderMethod` in the `yield` function. Look at [here in the doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider) to see what I exactly mean.

Comment: I believe my yields are formatted in that way, I have self.parse_dir_contents as described in the documentation. Thank you for your comments, I will look into requests per minute